# $\{a_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ diverges to $+\infty$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $$ a_n =
\begin{cases}
n,  & \text{if $n$ is odd} \\
\frac{1}{n}, & \text{if $n$ is even}
\end{cases}$$
Does $\{a_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ diverge to $+\infty$?

Comment: Neither diverges nor converges (by definition)

Comment: Is it true that for any $B$ there is an $N$ such that $a_n\gt B$ whenever $n\gt N$?

Answer (score 3):

The sequence *diverges* (defined as "not converges"), but it does not *diverge to infinity* (defined as: For every $M$ there exists $N$ such that $n>N$ implies $a_n>M$).

Answer (score 1):

The entire sequence does not converge since the values do not evenly go to a single value (one half of the sequence grows without bound and the other half gets closer and closer to zero)

However, the entire sequence does not diverge to $+\infty$ either. We say $\{a_n\} \to \infty$ if for any $M$ there is an $N$ for which $n > N \implies a_n > M$. If we choose $M = 1$, there is no such $N$ because there will be the even terms which are less than $1$.

So the sequence just simply diverges (not to $\infty$ or any other value - divergence simply means non-convergence, which doesn't necessarily mean it goes to infinity)